# Change Firebase Realtime Database POJO properties using @PropertyName, How to migrate existing data

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, database-migration

I have an app already in production, and now I want to change database property names in several tables to reduce bandwidth.

For eg, realtime database existing property is:

```
   purchasePrice: 60
```

and by using @PropertyName, I want to change it so it now looks like this:

```
   pp: 60
```

The changed POJO now has @PropertyName like:

```
   @PropertyName("pp")
   public float purchasePrice;
```

The question is: What is the best migration strategy so that all existing 'purchasePrice' is updated to new name in the realtime database, i.e 'pp' in this example case?

One naive approach I can think of is, on app update at client end, pull all data using old POJOs and assign each property to new POJOs (newPOJO.pp = oldPOJO.purchasePrice) and then save it in DB. But there should be a better way, as I have many POJOs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the name of a field in the database everywhere it occurs, there is really no easy way to do this. You're going to have to:

1. Query all of the nodes where it could appear
2. Check to see if the field needs to change
3. Write the new data back to that location

Whether you do that with code that uses @PropertyName or something more generic, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: How about making a backward compatibility method like, public void setPurchasePrice(float p){ purchasePrice = p}, in POJOs

Comment: If that meets your needs, sure.

Comment: If I go with your original advice, that would mean create new POJOs with annotated names, on migration read using old POJOs and then tranform into new POJOs and save?

Comment: You don't need any POJOs at all to implement my advice.  You can simply read and write data using the native Map objects provided by the SDK in a batch process that runs outside of your app.

Comment: Its an android app, are you referring to cloud functions for batch process? And If I run outside of my app, wouldn't it break old users who havent migrated yet.

Comment: I'm referring to any process that runs outside your app.  Your question does not clearly define how your migration must behave, so you have a lot of flexibiity in how you want to solve this.  There is no one correct way to do it.  But if you must migrate from within your app, you will have problems in the long run.  Some data may simply never migrate at all if it's never accessed. The only way to guarantee a full migration is to do it all at once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219134/discussion-between-droidbee-and-doug-stevenson).